# ng:btstrpd err App Already Bootstrapped with this Element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, ngroute

It's entirely possible I'm doing something stupid ...
Full stack trace of the Error

> Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element < html class="js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths ng-scope mdl-js js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache

This Error is occuring in my index.html file.by default i route to login.html.it goes on continous loop.so many ng-view are getting created.
this is my script.js and index.html

```js
// create the module and name it app
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','luegg.directives']);

// configure our routes
app.factory("Data", function(){
var pagesData = {};
var loginData = {};
var data = {};
// var setPageName = function(x){
//   pagesData.pageName = x;
//   console.log(x);
// };
//
// var setPageId = function(x){
//   pagesData.pageId = x;
//   console.log(x);
// };
// var getPageData = function(){
//   return pagesData;
// };
// return {pageData : pagesData.pageName};
return {

 getpageData : function () {
   console.log(pagesData);
   return pagesData;
 },

 setPageName : function (name) {
   pagesData.pageName = name;
   console.log("1111111111111");
   console.log(pagesData);
 },
 setPageId : function (id) {
   pagesData.pageId = id;
   console.log("1111111111111");
   console.log(pagesData);
 },
 setUserName : function (name) {
   loginData.userName = name;
   console.log("1111111111111");
   console.log(pagesData);
 },
 setUserEmail : function (mail) {
   loginData.userEmail = mail;
   console.log("1111111111111");
   console.log(pagesData);
 },
 getLoginData : function () {
   console.log(pagesData);
   return loginData;
 }


}
});
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'login-2.html',
    controller  : 'loginCtrl'
   })

      .when('/page', {
    templateUrl : 'pages.html',
    controller  : 'myPagesCtrl'
   })

   .when('/try', {
    templateUrl : 'try.html',
    controller  : 'myctrl'
   });

});
app.controller('myPagesCtrl', function($scope) {
  // create a message to display in our view
  $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
 });

 app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
 });

  app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$location) {
 scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
<title> Monarch UI - Bootstrap Frontend &amp; Admin Template </title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.light_blue-blue.min.css" />
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
<!-- Favicons -->

<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../../assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../../assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../../assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../../assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/images/icons/favicon.png">



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">


<!-- HELPERS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/backgrounds.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/boilerplate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/border-radius.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/page-transitions.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/spacing.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/typography.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/utils.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/colors.css">

<!-- ELEMENTS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/badges.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/buttons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/content-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/dashboard-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/forms.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/images.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/info-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/invoice.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/loading-indicators.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/menus.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/panel-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/response-messages.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/responsive-tables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/ribbon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/social-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/tables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/tile-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/elements/timeline.css">



<!-- ICONS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/icons/fontawesome/fontawesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/icons/linecons/linecons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/icons/spinnericon/spinnericon.css">


<!-- WIDGETS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/accordion-ui/accordion.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/calendar/calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/carousel/carousel.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/charts/justgage/justgage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/charts/morris/morris.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/charts/piegage/piegage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/charts/xcharts/xcharts.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/chosen/chosen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/colorpicker/colorpicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/datatable/datatable.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/datepicker/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/datepicker-ui/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/dialog/dialog.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/dropdown/dropdown.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/dropzone/dropzone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/file-input/fileinput.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/input-switch/inputswitch.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/input-switch/inputswitch-alt.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/ionrangeslider/ionrangeslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/jcrop/jcrop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/jgrowl-notifications/jgrowl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/loading-bar/loadingbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/maps/vector-maps/vectormaps.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/markdown/markdown.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/modal/modal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/multi-select/multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/multi-upload/fileupload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/nestable/nestable.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/noty-notifications/noty.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/popover/popover.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/pretty-photo/prettyphoto.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/progressbar/progressbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/range-slider/rangeslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/slidebars/slidebars.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/slider-ui/slider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/summernote-wysiwyg/summernote-wysiwyg.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/tabs-ui/tabs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/theme-switcher/themeswitcher.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/timepicker/timepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/tocify/tocify.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/tooltip/tooltip.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/touchspin/touchspin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/uniform/uniform.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/wizard/wizard.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/widgets/xeditable/xeditable.css">

<!-- SNIPPETS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/chat.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/files-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/login-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/notification-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/progress-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/todo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/user-profile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/snippets/mobile-navigation.css">

<!-- APPLICATIONS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/applications/mailbox.css">

<!-- Admin theme -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/themes/admin/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/themes/admin/color-schemes/default.css">

<!-- Components theme -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/themes/components/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/themes/components/border-radius.css">

<!-- Admin responsive -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/responsive-elements.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/helpers/admin-responsive.css">

    <!-- JS Core -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/jquery-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/jquery-ui-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/jquery-ui-widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/jquery-ui-mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/interactions-ui/sortable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/jquery.ns-autogrow/dist/jquery.ns-autogrow.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/jquery-ui-position.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/transition.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js-core/jquery-cookie.js"></script>




    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/angular/app.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/angular/page-animations.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myPagesController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/about.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/loginController.js"></script>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.0/lock.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/chosen-sort.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/chosen/chosen.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/chosen/chosen-demo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/accordion-ui/accordion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/angularjs-scroll-glue/src/scrollglue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/angular-xeditable/js/xeditable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/wizard/wizard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/wizard/wizard-demo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/tabs/tabs.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/widgets/parsley/parsley.js"></script>

</head>


    <body>
      <div ng-view>

      </div>
      <!-- <button><a href="#/pages"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></button>
        <a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a> -->


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is this:

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'index.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
  })
```

You don't need to specify 'index.html' here. index.html will be loaded by your server. You need to pass what template file to load into the ng-view that is in that index.html when the '/' path is detected.

edit: As mentioned in my comments. You also should only have 1 ng-app directive in your application. This directive bootstraps angular and is only needed once.

Comment: Hey thanks.tried your answer.same is happening.please see the updated script.js.do you know why this is happening.?

Comment: Are you using ng-app="app" anywhere else? Also are you using <pre>angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']); </pre> anywhere? Is it possible you're loading angular twice? These things could also cause this issue by attempting to bootstrap your app multiple times.

Comment: Yes I am using ng-app='app' in login.html and index.html and try.html

Comment: You'll need to remove it from all but the index.html page. It is only needed once. I can update my answer above with this info.

Comment: But for routing can it be different apps can be used??

Comment: The routes you define within the router are for 1 app which you can only bootstrap 1 time with ng-app. If you want to have separate apps then they would have their own routers and also I believe you cannot use ng-app to bootstrap multiple angular apps you have to bootstrap within your JS  with angular.bootstrap. See here for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: Yes.exactly I need a single app. So I used 'app' for index and login.html.if I change the app of of index.html will the route work.?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by that. The bottom line is ng-app="app" can only be in your application 1 time. It should be in your index.html as shown and nowhere else. var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','luegg.directives']); then creates an angular module that will be bootstrapped on load. If you have any more questions you can open a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133830/discussion-between-dmungin-and-kragor).